# Does CURL in PHP support SPDY?

Tags: php, curl, spdy

I am using cURL in PHP to connect to different APIs that I know use SPDY the new protocol from Google.

But I am unsure if by default PHP cURL supports SPDY. And if it is not is there a way to configure it so that it supports SPDY?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php has a list of supported protocols. As `libcurl` doesn't support SPDY yet, there is no way to add it.

Comment: Well that sucks. Will it be supported soon?

Comment: Support is planned - https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/docs/ROADMAP.md - but there's no timeframe for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on my system with PHP 5.5.19, and curl 7.39.0 , the answer is no. 
You can check what your curl  support, by enabling "automatic" encoding, making curl list all supported encodings to the server  (enable automatic by CURLOPT_ENCODING->empty string), then check the headers sent by curl, like this:

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists("curlcall",$_GET)){
    if(is_callable("http_get_request_headers")){
    var_dump(http_get_request_headers());       
    }elseif(is_callable("apache_request_headers")){
        var_dump(apache_request_headers());
    } else {
        throw new Exception("unsupported enviroment (both http_get_request_headers and apache_request_headers missing!)");
    }
    } else {
    $ch=curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/a.php?curlcall");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
    curl_exec($ch);
    }
```

on my system, i get this output:

```
array(3) { ["Host"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["Accept"]=> string(3) "*/*" 
["Accept-Encoding"]=> string(13) "deflate, gzip" }
```

meaning that deflate and gzip (and the default - no encoding/plain) is supported (no SPDY support yet im afriad)